# ASP.NET 2.0: how to use XPath?

Tags: asp.net, xpath

If we can get a collection of **x nodes** via XPath in ASP.NET 2.0? Then doing checking per the attrs of them.

```
<x-list>
  <x id="1" enable="On" url="http://abc.123.dev"/>
  <x id="2" enable="Off" url="http://asd.com"/>
  <x id="3" enable="On" url="http://plm.xcv.tw"/>
</x-list>
```

Thanks for any help.
Ricky

Comment: I was just wondering why enable attribute is not a boolean field

Comment: Also, what language do you use, C# or VB?

Comment: Consider, that if you have been using a higher version of .NET with VB you could enjoy the goodies of VB XML literals: http://ookii.org/post/xml_literals_in_visual_basic_9.aspx

Comment: @Shimmy: good question. That is designed by somebody else.

Comment: @Shimmy Because the values in the document are "On" and "Off", not "true" and "false". The former are not boolean values. See the XML specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample that'll retrieve all of your 'x' nodes that are enabled:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/x-list/x[@enable='On']");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  ...
}
```

I find w3schools a good place to look for [XPath tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: Also: http://oreilly.com/catalog/xmlnut/chapter/ch09.html and (using PERL) http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html

Comment: Another question: how to apply "AND" to attributes selectors

Comment: And do you know how to make the XPath query case-"in"sensitive?

Comment: XPath is case-sensitive.  You'd be better off enforcing correct case in your documents. If you absolutely have to do case-insensitive queries, look into the translate() function:  http://shujaatsiddiqi.blogspot.com/2009/02/xpath-for-case-insensitive-search.html

Comment: Look to the XPath tutorial (specifically, the page describing operators) for information on its boolean operators.
http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_operators.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);

XmlNodeList xList = xDocument.SelectNodes("x-list/x");

if (xList.Count > 0)
{
 foreach (XmlNode x in xList)
     {
         string id = x.Attributes["id"].Value;
  string enable = x.Attributes["enable"].Value;
  string url = x.Attributes["url"].Value;

  if (enable.Equals("On")
  {
   ...
  }
  else
  {
   ...
  }

 }
}
else
{
...
}
```